# HashiCorp Vault sealing questions

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I've started playing with Hashicorp's Vault to manage secrets and had some questions about the day-to-day of Vault sealing.  My workflow has two auth backends; specific users access Vault with write access to add new secrets, servers have readonly access for the secrets they need.

1) Under normal circumstances, does the Vault stay in an unsealed state?  I believe it would as a dynamically provisioned server should not have to coordinate an unseal.

2) Is the purpose of sealing to off-board staff to rotate keys and in case of an intrusion?

3) What's the best practice for ensuring the vault process is always running, since if it dies the Vault will seal?  Also, in a highly available configuration, if one Vault node's process dies, does it seal the Vault for everyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked this question on the Vault Google Group and this was the best response:

`1) Under normal circumstances, does the Vault stay in an unsealed
state? I believe it would as a dynamically provisioned server should
not have to coordinate an unseal.`

Yes. Once Vault is initialized and unsealed, it 'normally' stays in an
unsealed state.

`2) Is the purpose of sealing to off-board staff to rotate keys and in
case of an intrusion?`

Sealing of Vault enables a turn key mechanism to stop all the services
of Vault. It would require a specific number of unseal key holders to
make Vault operational again.

`3) What's the best practice for ensuring the vault process is always
running, since if it dies the Vault will seal? Also, in a highly
available configuration, if one Vault node's process dies, does it
seal the Vault for everyone?`

There is no official best practice recommendation for this. But
running Vault in a dedicated instance/cluster with very
limited/no-access to its memory. Running Vault in a HA mode using a
backend which supports it is good. If any of the cluster nodes goes
down or if the Vault process is restarted, it will be in a sealed
state and would require the unseal operation to be performed to make
it operational.

Best,
Vishal

Answer (score 2):

Taken from https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/seal.html:

1. "Under normal circumstances, does the Vault stay in an unsealed state?" -

> When a Vault server is started, it starts in a sealed state. In this state, Vault is configured to know where and how to access the physical storage, but doesn't know how to decrypt any of it.
>
> Unsealing is the process of constructing the master key necessary to
>   read the decryption key to decrypt the data, allowing access to the
>   Vault.
>
> Prior to unsealing, almost no operations are possible with Vault. For
>   example authentication, managing the mount tables, etc. are all not possible. The only possible operations are to unseal the Vault and check the status of the unseal.

2. "Is the purpose of sealing to off-board staff to rotate keys and in case of an intrusion?" -

> This way, if there is a detected intrusion, the Vault data can be locked
>   quickly to try to minimize damages. It can't be accessed again without  access to the master key shards.

3. "since if it dies the Vault will seal?" - yes.